# Maven Surefire plugin run time faliure

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Created a maven project with following plugin tag in POM

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>central</id>
    <name>Central Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <forkCount>3</forkCount>
            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Project Structure
[image: Project Structure]
The test source has a single file named `MainTest.java`.

When i run `mvn clean package -e` without any test file it runs fine.
But after adding a test file i.e. `MainTest.java`, following error appears

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project app: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create test class 'com.app.MainTest' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project app: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create test class 'com.app.MainTest'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
```

I have also tried changing maven-surefire-plugin versions and configurations but still no progress.
Help !!!

Comment: The problem is located here: `:test failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create test class 'com.app.MainTest'`  ..apart from that without the full pom file and  the directory structure as well as the culprit class it's hard to guess what's wrong?...

Comment: Hello @khmarbaise, i have added the project structure and full POM file.

Comment: Configuring maven central in your pom is not needed cause it's default so you can remove it..furthermore the test class is missing? Furthermore why do you need the memory configurations for your unit tests?

Comment: I was just trying to fix the issue, so i thought may be adding maven central may fix the issue, yes i can remove it. About memory config, there was another error where build was crashing and this fixed the issue. Which test class is missing? @khmarbaise